# IsPersistent not working - Cookie only valid for current session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have an `ASP.NET MVC 5` application using `ASP.NET Identity 2.1.0` for user authentication.
Everything worked fine in the past, but now I found out that persisting user sessions does not work anymore. I can not tell what change broke this, but it worked when I implemented Identity (converted the application from `SimpleMembership`) and this is my logic I have at the moment:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                                     model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

`SignInManager` is my `ApplicationSignInManager` based on `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>` and `model.RememberMe` is `true`.

And my setup:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = ApplicationCookieIdentityValidator.OnValidateIdentity(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
    });
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Everything works fine, except persisting the user sessions. I checked the cookies returned by my server and the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` is allways returned as "valid for current session" instead of some date in the future. So when I close and reopen the browser I need to log in again...

**Does anybody have an idea why this is not working (anymore)?**

P.S.: I have overriden `SignInAsync` in my `ApplicationSignInManager` because I do some custom logic there, but I even checked with the debugger and for the following call:

```
await base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
```

`isPersistent` is `true`, so it should create a persisten cookie.

Comment: I suspect `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)` can cause this. Because on every request it regenerates cookie and sets a new one. Try setting `validateInterval` to something more than 0 and see if that works.

Comment: @trailmax: Thanks, that was it. Was that changes with V 2.1? Because it definitely worked in the beginning (with V 2.0). Anyhow: Post this as an answer and I will accept it. I now need to find away around this, as I need (because of SSO) validation on every request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is a known bug in Identity](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2319) and by looking on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621119/809357) it is not very new.

When cookie is regenerated on every request, "IsPersisted" flag is not set, when, even when it was set in the original cookie.

To work around this, you will need to implement your own version of cookie validator that will set the flag as is should.

I think I've got the solution for you, but I have not compiled or tested it - just merely a general direction of where you need to go. See this [gist for full code](https://gist.github.com/trailmax/e51790f31c8c68749ec0).
This is just a `SecurityStampValidator` code taken from decompiler. I've [added lines 91-96](https://gist.github.com/trailmax/e51790f31c8c68749ec0#file-securitystampvalidator-cs-L91-L96). Basically I take "IsPersistent" flag from the previous cookie and add it to the new cookie, when it is created. That was not done in non-modified version.

And then in your Auth.Config you do:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = MySecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
```

Beware though, when new version is out, check if this was fixed, so you can remove the dirty fix. This issue is [reported to be fixed](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2319), but shortly after v2.1 was out.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. As I already have my own validator (see `ApplicationCookieIdentityValidator` in my code) I just needed to add your changes there too -> working!

Comment: @ChrFin Yes, I noticed the name is different from the standard. Glad it helps!

Comment: nice code! Looks like it is missing `using Microsoft.Owin.Security;` to access the `AuthenticationProperties` type though

Comment: This works for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946582/how-ispersistent-works-in-owin-cookie-authentication/46659752#46659752

Comment: @Sergey a year? more like 4 years since my answer. Identity 2 is not getting developed anymore, what do you expect?

Comment: This code is almost perfect!, Just in the case that any other developer out there is having issues with the Two Factor Authentication setup, just change `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)` to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` as stated in the [official help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity)

Answer (score 1):

Updating both `AspNet.Identity.Core` and `AspNet.Identity.Owin` to 2.2.1 should resolve this issue.

Comment: after updating it still has same problem and even default template for asp.mvc for Identity core has the same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946582/how-ispersistent-works-in-owin-cookie-authentication/46659752#46659752

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep a user loggedin on browser close in Mvc Indentity. The below code is what worked for me in Startup.Auth.cs class.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                    { 
                        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                        SlidingExpiration = true,
                        CookieHttpOnly = false,
                        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

                        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                        {  
                            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),

                                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => 
                                user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),

                            OnResponseSignIn = context => {
                                context.Properties.IsPersistent = true; };
                            } 
        }
```

Comment: FYI, you should not be using `CookieHttpOnly = false` here. It should be set to true or omitted (since true is the default). An HTTP only cookie cannot be accessed by JavaScript in the browser. But with this code, malicious JavaScript from a cross site scripting attack could yank your user's auth cookie.