# How IsPersistent works in OWIN Cookie authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

It seems I don't understand clearly how `IsPersistent` in OWIN cookie authentication works, the code below is to use `IsPersistent`:

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authManager = context.Authentication;
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistence };

authManager.SignIn(properties, identity);
```

I don't see the difference when user checks/unchecks `Remember me` (uses `IsPersistent` behind) because if I close Chrome browser and open it again to go with the website, the cookie `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` is still there and it lets me in even I check or uncheck `Remember me`.

I have checked the definition of `IsPersistent` on the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationproperties(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Gets or sets whether the authentication session is persisted across multiple requests.

But don't get much understanding since I see it still works.

The code to setup OWIN cookie authentication:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = ApplicationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOn")
});
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Persistent cookies will be saved as files in the browser folders until they either expire or manually deleted. This will cause the cookie to persist even if you close the browser.

If IsPersistent is set to false, the browser will acquire session cookie which gets cleared when the browser is closed.

Now the reason session cookie wont clear after restarting the browser is because of chrome default settings.
To fix it go to chrome *settings* -> *advanced*, and uncheck **Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed** under *System* section.

Comment: Awesome answer, this is the first time I know this setting, thanks a lot

Comment: Actually there is another Chrome setting that will impact whether browser clears cookie.  It is "continue where you left off"  Good answer at ths [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33904951/2788458)  If set then cookie is not cleared

Comment: As of this date, and under .net core 3.1, "continue running in background" had no influence in my testing. What DID have an effect is "continue where you left off" Since I wanted to ensure the user was always logged out, I placed the following code in the initial controller executed at startup: 

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User))
            {
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                return RedirectToAction();
            }

            return View();
        }

Comment: As of 28.10.2020 MVC 5.2 asp.net 4 both options Continue running ... and Continue where ...do not have any effect on the cookie - it persists between tab/browser closes

Answer (score 5):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Some Code
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(GetCookieAuthenticationOptions());
    //Some Code
}

private static CookieAuthenticationOptions GetCookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    var options  = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
    {
        CookieName = "AuthCookie",  //Some cookie settings here
    };
    var provider = (CookieAuthenticationProvider)options.Provider;
    provider.OnResponseSignIn = (context) => 
    {
        context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
    };
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Not working for core. There is no CookieAuthenticationProvider in Core Library.

Comment: Saved my day. was trying to do it with OnValidateIdentity first but it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Balaji Gunasekaran**, thanks for your answer.

But I have some modifications, maybe somebody will use it:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieName = "YourCookieName",
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),

            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                {
                    context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                },

            }
        });
```

I spent some time learning the source code of the OWIN library, and I found we need to enable only the IsPersistent flag using provider, other properties we need to change in default settings.

This example is actual to 4.2.0 version of the OWIN Library. (ASP.NET MVC5 .NET Framework 4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Persistent cookies  for .Net Core 2.2 you might want to try this

Example

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
 { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "test"),},CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties
{
  IsPersistent = true,
  ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)
});
```