# .NET Identity auth cookie expiration

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I read quite a few tutorials and posts regarding this, but somewhere along the line I must still be missing something.

With the below code I expected the user to be signed out within max 1 minute from browser close (validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)), unless 'remember me' is set.

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                 AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                 SlidingExpiration = true,
                 ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                 LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                 Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                 {
                      OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                 }
            });
```

However, whether or not 'remember me' is set seems to make no difference, the user stays logged in for 1 hour after browser close (ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).

My understanding is, 'remember me' means persistent cookie, so if it's not set the cookie should get destroyed when the browser closes, at the latest when validateInterval has passed.

Where am I going wrong and what do I need to set so the user is signed out after 1 hour of inactivity or 1 minute of browser close (whichever comes first)?

Comment: With regards to the cookie not getting cleared when the user closes the browser, are you by chance using Chrome? If so, the issue may be with the browser itself and not ASP.NET, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32052308/6137718

Comment: yes, I had read that somewhere and for that reason also tried FF; it happens in both (sorry, forgot to mentioned it)