# ABP cookie expiration time issue

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ABP v3.3.0. In this version, I have some new experience. My application asks for login every 30 minutes, because my `SignIn` method takes in 30 minutes expiration time:

```
_authenticationManager.SignIn(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthSession.ExpireTimeInMinutes.WhenNotPersistent"] ?? "30"))
    },
    identity);
```

In my `Startup` class, I found this code:

```
// by setting following values, the auth cookie will expire after the
//  configured amount of time (default 14 days) when user set the
//  (IsPermanent == true) on the login
ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthSession.ExpireTimeInDays.WhenPersistent"] ?? "14"), 0, 0, 0),
```

But in `AccountController`, there is no property named `IsPermanent`. `AuthenticationProperties` is an object that has a property named `IsPersistent`.

I guess it is a spelling mistake. If not, please help me to find `IsPermanent` property on login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ABP uses **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication**'s [AuthenticationManager.SignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationmanager.signinasync) method and [AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties.ispersistent) property.

It works with the "Remember Me" checkbox on the login page.

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052308/8601760):

> Persistent cookies will be saved as files in the browser folders until they either expire or manually deleted. This will cause the cookie to persist even if you close the browser.
>
> If IsPersistent is set to false, the browser will acquire session cookie which gets cleared when the browser is closed.
>
> Now the reason session cookie wont clear after restarting the browser is because of chrome default settings. To fix it go to chrome settings -> advanced, and uncheck Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed under System section.

Yes, it is a spelling mistake.