# Why won't 'Remember Me' work in VS2013's ASP.NET MVC 5 boilerplate code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using VS2013, I create a new project -> ASP.NET Web Application -> MVC only (no WebAPI or anything else.)

A load of handy boilerplate code is created, including the expected login management stuff, using OWIN.

For the sake of simple testing, I change the CookieAuthentication options to a short timeout in Startup.Auth.cs (add ExpireTimeSpan and set validateInterval).

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Fire it up (F5, which runs locally with IISExpress and uses LocalDB), register and wait two minutes. Click the 'Hello, [username]!' link at the top (which invokes an [Authorize]d controller method.) Logged out as expected.

Log in again with 'Remember me' checked. Wait two minutes. Click same link. Logged out again! Why is this? I expected an indefinite login. Have I misunderstood what this does?

My System.Web.Mvc.dll has version number 5.2.3-30128.0.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer [ExpireTimeSpan ignored after regenerateIdentity / validateInterval duration in MVC Identity (2.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983726/expiretimespan-ignored-after-regenerateidentity-validateinterval-duration-in-m)

`regenerateIdentity` is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen that question, but my extensive googling had brought up that link the second answer has. The whole situation's very odd - nobody seems to care that Remember Me in its simplest form doesn't seem to work out of the box! And MS on codeplex are claiming the issue's fixed, when it's clearly not.

Comment: "Remember Me in its simplest form doesn't seem to work out of the box" - @spudnick

This is why I tend to leave the feature out and hope no one notices.  :)