# ASP Identity CookieAuthentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

So I have a MVC5 web application and I'm using the built in ASP.Identity framework for authentication. I want to let my user keep their login status for 30 days.

here's my code in `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieName = "Test",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
            });
```

I checked the cookie after login and it's true that the expiration is 30 days, but after few minutes/hours when I'm trying to access the site again, the login status is gone. Any idea why?

Comment: Do your users have any value in `SecurityStamp` field in the database?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a bug in `OnValidateIdentity`. Whenever it try to regenerates the cookies it set the `IsPersistent` to `false`, even if the original cookie is persistent.

If i am not wrong, you might be facing this issue after closing and reopening the browser. This issue can be resolved by adding an IsPersistent claims manualy, try looking in to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983726/expiretimespan-ignored-after-regenerateidentity-validateinterval-duration-in-m)